# Rails named scope not working on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following association: a seller can define payment methods for each buyer.

What I want to be able to do is something like

```
a_seller = Seller.find(34)
a_buyer = Buyer.find(22)

a_buyer.payment_methods_for_seller a_seller
```

Simple, I thought:

```
class SellerBuyerPaymentMethod < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyer
  belongs_to :seller
end

class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :seller_buyer_payment_methods
  scope :payment_methods_for_seller, ->(seller) { joins(:seller_buyer_payment_methods).where(:seller => seller) }
end
```

But I get the error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `payment_methods_for_seller' for Buyer:0x000001028e6d88

This works:

```
class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :seller_buyer_payment_methods

  def payment_methods_for_seller seller
    SellerBuyerPaymentMethod.where( :buyer => self, :seller => seller )
  end
end
```

But I feel I should be able to do this with scopes. There's something simple I'm missing here. Any help much appreciated...

Rails 4.1, Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rails scopes are just class methods**. Internally Active Record converts a scope into a class method. So, when you define this scope:

```
  scope :payment_methods_for_seller, ->(seller) { joins(:seller_buyer_payment_methods).where(:seller => seller) }
```

You can consider this `payment_methods_for_seller` method as a class method of `Buyer` class. That's why you get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `payment_methods_for_seller' for Buyer:0x000001028e6d88
```

when you called the class method on an object of the `Buyer` class:

```
a_buyer.payment_methods_for_seller a_seller
```

You can't call a scope/class method on an object of the class. You can call it on the class itself:

```
Buyer.payment_methods_for_seller
```

The 2nd example works because in that case you defined the `payment_methods_for_seller` method as an instance method of the `Buyer` class.

Hope this clears your confusion.

Instead of using scopes you can get the relevant records through the seller_buyer_methods association:

```
a_buyer.seller_buyer_payment_methods.where( :seller => a_seller )
```

Here is a nice blog post on [Active Record scopes vs class methods](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/) which will give you some more interesting information on this topic.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think my confusion was because of the example on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes where the scope is run on the association e.g. 'category.articles.published'. Actually I can see what the right answer is now - a_buyer.seller_buyer_payment_methods.where( :seller => a_seller ). Thanks for sending me in the right direction : )

Answer (score 1):

OK, the answer is simply:

```
a_buyer.seller_buyer_payment_methods.where( :seller => a_seller )
```

Thanks to K M Rakibul Islam for putting me in the right direction...